# Are there any tracked music libraries for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Is anyone aware of any Delphi libraries (Delphi code, not external DLLs with Delphi interfaces) available for playing tracked music, referring to formats such as MOD, IT, S3M, XM, etc?  It would need to work correctly under Delphi XE.

Comment: Do you want to read the structures, or do you want an actual player?

Comment: @Wouter: Looking for an actual player.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for that in the past as well, but you almost always end up with a wrapper around a dll, either commercial or free (bass, fmod, modplug).

[OpenModPas](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openmodpas/) seems to be an attempt to implement a full pascal implementation, but I haven't tried it myself. The code repository looks a bit messy, and the project looks kind of dead (last update:2006-11-17)

I'll try to get it to work in XE after I post this.. if I find anything interesting I'll come back with an update.

...

Ok, OpenModPas is just the start of a project.. it's mostly placeholders, and there's no functional code yet, but if you're interested in reading the structures of modules you can probably use parts of it.

...

There's some cool code by Benjamin Rosseaux here (MiniMod, and BeRoXM):
http://bero.0ok.de/downloads/

It's all pascal, doesn't seem to use any .dll's and it plays modules with advanced effects amazingly accurate. It has some player code, and for ultimate weirdness it also seems to be able to generate a pascal unit from a tracker file.

Anyway, let me know if you run into something interesting yourself

Comment: Interesting stuff, but apparently there's no support for .IT format, which I need, and BeRoXM does require an external DLL.  (Search for "coredll" in BeRoXM.pas.)  The Mod-to-code thing is awesome, though, just in its own right.  I'll have to look at that. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Mason Wheeler: I'm the author of BeRoXM, MiniMOD and BeRoTracker. "coredll" of WindowsCE/WindowsMobile is the "kernel32.dll" of Desktop Windows, so BeRoXM needs it only in the WindowsCE build, otherwise it needs no external DLLs for another targets. 
And if you need .it playback, then ask me for the BeRoTracker ( http://www.berotracker.de/ ) player engine (under the condition, that you'll not share these object pascal sources of it with others then), because the BeRoTracker player engine can load (and even save again) and play various module file formats including MOD S3M XM IT IMF BRT OKT MTM and so on.
BeRoXM is primary designed for embedded targets like Android and so on with usage of FreePascal.

Comment: Hi, BeRo.  What's a good way to get in touch with you? I tried to email you about BRT a while back, using the contact information on your blog, and never got a response.  Is that out of date?